# call flow with screen from visualforce page is not working

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

call flow with screen from visualforce page is not working, not sure what is wrong?

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract">
 <flow:interview name="ContractTracer" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/home/home.jsp')}">
   <apex:param name="varContractID" value="{!Contract.Id}" />  
</flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

debug:

> 17:16:20.0 (497962)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>   17:16:20.0 (505017)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|066C0000000MIcW|VF: /apex/RestrictedAccessAlert
>   17:16:20.23 (23090882)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00DV000000897H7|300V00000008iSb|301V0000000BDMq
>   17:16:20.23 (23221134)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|2542f2a5f00b3cfc23ce37ecec7f16b1a00b2fb-5480|ContractAccessTracker
>   17:16:20.23 (23551222)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|2542f2a5f00b3cfc23ce37ecec7f16b1a00b2fb-5480|ContractAccessTracker
>   17:16:20.23 (81316605)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|2542f2a5f00b3cfc23ce37ecec7f16b1a00b2fb-5480|ContractAccessTracker
>   17:16:20.0 (99303175)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|066C0000000MIcW
>   17:16:20.0 (102730287)|VF_SERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END
>   17:16:20.106 (106496620)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE

did not see anything wrong in log as well.

Comment: What specific behavior are you seeing when you lead the page, and how does it differ from expected functionality? (Please [edit] to add information).

Comment: @davidReed I am expecting it to run the flow but it is not working. The flow is working when I call from Aura component.  I tried in classic first, so i am expecting to the see the screen flow.